# wcf service for pdf to tiff conversion using Ghostscript

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have to create a WCF service for the pdf to tif conversion. The service should –

1)  Accept as input two strings – input file path, and output file path
2)  It should convert the input (pdf) file and store it as a tif file on the given output path

Please help me with this as i am new to wcf concepts.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let discus possible solution. Simple WCF service with HTTP binding.

You will need some API to perform transformation from PDF.

First create Class Library and put something like this in it:

```
// WCF Service interface
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

[ServiceContract]
public interface IPdfConvertor
{
 [OperationContract]
 void PdfToTif(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath);
}
```

Than you have to implement interface

// WCF service implementation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, 
        IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
public class PdfConvertor:IPdfConvertor
{
  public void PdfToTif(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
  {
    // Perform conversion here
  }
}
```

That's about service. When you make it you have to choose how to host it. 
You have several options for hosting:
1) IIS
2) Windows Service
3) Windows .NET Application

Wherever to host it. You have to configure endpoints. Put your configuration in Web.config or App.config something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SomeNameSpace.PdfConvertor" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceMetadataBehavior">
        <endpoint contract="SomeNameSpace.IPdfConvertor" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPdfConvertor" binding="basicHttpBinding" address="http://localhost:8000/PdfConvertor"/>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPdfConvertor"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceMetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8000/mex" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

This is just a skeleton. I hope to help you to take some idea of possible solution for you problem.

Also try to read some basic tutorial about wcf : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx